# windows.onload event

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I'm embedding a flash object in an html page and calling windows.onload to initialize the Flash movie. The problem is that the windows.onload does not wait for the Flash object to completely load. Is there way to make sure that the Flash object has fully loaded?
Here is the code I'm using:

```
<head>
<script>
var falshObj = null;
 function pageInit()
 {
    thisMovie();
    //alert("test");
    falshObj.init();// function within the Flash Object
 }
function thisMovie() 
{
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) 
    {
        falshObj = window["main"];//Flash object name
    } 
    else 
    {
        falshObj = document["main"];//Flash object name
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body >
<script>
if (window.addEventListener) 
{
    window.addEventListener("load", pageInit, false);
} 
else 
{
    window.attachEvent("onload", pageInit);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash is totally async to the rest of the browser.  You'd need to utilize an externalInterface call back to the JavaScript in order to notify it that the movie has loaded.

Also, your JS syntax is antiquated and error prone, but that's a different discussion.

Comment: the falshObj.init() is an externalInterface callback which initializes the movie.

Comment: No, you need the flash to notify the JavaScript that it is ready to load, although I'm not entirely sure why.  Perhaps you're attempting to synchronize Flash with something in the browser?  If not, then the least you need to do is just have the Flash ExternalInterface call a 'loaded' JS function, then call init on the loaded object (assuming there's some reason you aren't auto-initing).

Comment: In fact, JS sends some data to the Flash movie once the page completes loading to trigger some functions in the Flash movie.